# Debugging Delta table source in Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

Suppose in my project there are lots of delta tables and i want to search that any particular delta table in databricks is loaded from which source. How can i search which script or source is loading that particular delta table in efficient manner in databricks workspace?

Looking for help in databricks workspace and expecting result related to debgging some table like what are the source which notebook it is loading etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with [Databricks Unity Catalog](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/index.html) and [Lineage functionality](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/data-lineage.html) inside it - it will give you ability to track what data sources were used to build a specific table, and what notebooks, etc. are reading from it or writing to it.

Without Unity Catalog it's harder - you either need to stick something to use for example, OpenLineage [presentation](https://www.databricks.com/session_na21/observability-for-data-pipelines-with-openlineage), and [instructions on how to setup it with Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/purview-adb-lineage-solution-accelerator/azure-databricks-to-purview-lineage-connector/).